# Is 128KHz oscillator in ATmega same as Watch Dog Oscillator?

Tags: arduino, atmel, atmega328p, watchdog

Where is the **128KHz oscillator located in ATmega328p**?

I am unable to find it on the ATmel data sheet ,**Is it same as watch dog timer Oscillator?**

I am attaching the clock section from the ATmel Datasheet below,There is no block labelled as 128KHz Oscillator?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

section 11.8 watchdog timer page 60

[image]